# How does Stack Overflow match similar questions?

Tags: support, similar-questions

I have a project that gives the ability to send suggestions and notes about something.

What I need is collecting (somewhat) similar suggestions or notes in groups.

My comparisons are based on key phrases and tags that the sender should obtain with the suggestions or notes.

What techniques does Stack Overflow use to match similar questions?

Comment: I took away your last sentence in the hope of keeping this on topic for you here. "How does SO x?" is sometimes on topic for meta. "How does [everyone, the whole internet, a number of unrelated products] do x?" is not on topic anywhere.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your clarification :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it :)